# Populating Javafx Table with data, using SceneBuilder

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I ve read quite some posts about populating Tables with data, but still can not understand.
I have created a table, actually 2 tables, with scene builder.
Yet i cant find how to populate at least one of these tables.

Every "Inventory" object has 2 arraylists, one is of type "Part", and one of type "Product". "Part" and "Product" are separate classes. "inHouse" is a child class of "Part".

Now, i have no idea how to use the initialize method in controller, I have made 1 observable list, and want to populate one of the tables with this list. How do i do that? Do i need to create an object of the controller Class? Where do i use the initialize method? What values do i pass? Where in the code do i use the vaiables of the columns and tables in the controller class?  I ve seen many posts but i just don't get it.

Here is the controller:

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

public class PartTable implements Initializable{

@FXML
private TreeTableView<Part> partTable;

@FXML
private TreeTableColumn<Part, Integer> partID;

@FXML
private TreeTableColumn<Part, String> partName;

@FXML
private TreeTableColumn<Part, Integer> inventoryLevel;

@FXML
private TreeTableColumn<Part, Double> partPrice;

@FXML
private TreeTableView<Product> productTable;

@FXML
private TreeTableColumn<Product, Integer> productID;

@FXML
private TreeTableColumn<Product, String> productName;

@FXML
private TreeTableColumn<Product, Integer> inventoryLevel2;

@FXML
private TreeTableColumn<Product, Double> productPrice;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    partID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("PartID"));
    partName.setCellFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Part Name"));
    inventoryLevel.setCellFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Inventory Level"));
    partPrice.setCellFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Price/Cost per Unit"));

}
```

}

Here is the Main.java(I know, many imports are redundant but anyways):

```
package application;



import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;


public class Main extends Application {



private TableView table1 = new TableView();



@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    try {


        Inventory i1 = new Inventory(); 
        i1.addPart(new InHouse(54534, "boli", 156.0, 2, 0, 100));
        i1.addPart(new InHouse(74541, "libo", 156.0, 2, 0, 100));
        i1.addPart(new InHouse(24551, "luci", 156.0, 2, 0, 100));
        i1.addPart(new InHouse(44581, "buci", 156.0, 2, 0, 100));
        i1.addPart(new InHouse(94531, "boluci", 156.0, 2, 0, 100));

        ObservableList<Part> oPart = FXCollections.observableList(i1.getPartList());

        PartTable table = new PartTable();




        Pane mainPane = (Pane)FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("MainMenu.fxml"));



        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setTitle("Inventory Management System");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();





    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Here is the fxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="482.0" prefWidth="1220.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.PartTable">
   <children>
      <HBox layoutX="7.0" layoutY="12.0" prefHeight="440.0" prefWidth="1200.0" spacing="30.0">
         <children>
            <GridPane prefHeight="440.0" prefWidth="600.0">
              <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
              </columnConstraints>
              <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints maxHeight="174.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="109.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints maxHeight="249.0" minHeight="9.0" prefHeight="218.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints maxHeight="284.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="108.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
              </rowConstraints>
               <children>
                  <GridPane GridPane.columnSpan="4">
                    <columnConstraints>
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                     <children>
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Search" GridPane.columnIndex="2">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="15.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Button>
                        <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.columnSpan="2" />
                        <Label prefHeight="63.0" prefWidth="88.0" text="Parts">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="17.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                     </children>
                  </GridPane>
                  <TreeTableView fx:id="partTable" prefHeight="220.0" prefWidth="100.0" GridPane.columnSpan="4" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                    <columns>
                      <TreeTableColumn fx:id="partID" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="PartID" />
                      <TreeTableColumn fx:id="partName" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="Part Name" />
                        <TreeTableColumn fx:id="inventoryLevel" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="Inventory Level" />
                        <TreeTableColumn fx:id="partPrice" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="Price/Cost per Unit" />
                    </columns>
                     <columnResizePolicy>
                        <TreeTableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                     </columnResizePolicy>
                  </TreeTableView>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="142.0" text="Delete" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="202.0" text="Modify" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="162.0" text="Add" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
               </children>
            </GridPane>
            <GridPane layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="440.0" prefWidth="600.0">
               <columnConstraints>
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
               </columnConstraints>
               <rowConstraints>
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="174.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="109.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="249.0" minHeight="9.0" prefHeight="218.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="284.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="108.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
               </rowConstraints>
               <children>
                  <GridPane GridPane.columnSpan="4">
                     <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                     </columnConstraints>
                     <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                     </rowConstraints>
                     <children>
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Search" GridPane.columnIndex="2">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="15.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Button>
                        <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.columnSpan="2" />
                        <Label prefHeight="63.0" prefWidth="88.0" text="Products">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="17.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                     </children>
                  </GridPane>
                  <TreeTableView fx:id="productTable" prefHeight="220.0" prefWidth="100.0" GridPane.columnSpan="4" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                     <columns>
                        <TreeTableColumn fx:id="productID" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="ProductID" />
                        <TreeTableColumn fx:id="productName" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="Product Name" />
                        <TreeTableColumn fx:id="inventoryLevel2" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="Inventory Level" />
                        <TreeTableColumn fx:id="productPrice" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="Price per Unit" />
                     </columns>
                     <columnResizePolicy>
                        <TreeTableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                     </columnResizePolicy>
                  </TreeTableView>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="142.0" text="Delete" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="172.0" text="Modify" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="219.0" text="Add" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
               </children>
            </GridPane>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

Comment: reading your very basic question (and glancing at your code), I would suggest to read a very basic tutorial first ;) See the info tab of the javafx tag for references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to actually do something with `oPart`.  Specifically, you want to pass it to your TableView’s [setItems](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#setItems(javafx.collections.ObservableList)) method.

Second, setCellFactory and setCell**Value**Factory are not the same thing.  Cell *value* factory determines the *data* in your table column;  the cell factory determines how that data is *displayed.*

Third, as the [documentation for PropertyValueFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html) explains, the String argument to the PropertyValueFactory constructor is *not* a column title, it’s the name of a bean property in the class of the table’s items.

A (writable) bean property consists of two methods:  a get-method and a set-method.  To determine the property name, remove the “get” and decapitalize the first letter of the remainder.  (It can be a bit more complicated than that, but that’s not directly relevant here.)

So, if your `Part` class has these methods:

```
public String getName() {
    // ...
}

public void setName(String name) {
    // ...
}
```

…then the corresponding property name is `name`, and that is the String you need to pass to PropertyValueFactory:

```
partName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("name"));
```

**However,** you can avoid reflection altogether, and thus be informed of mistakes by the compiler, if you have designed your `Part` class so that it has JavaFX-compliant properties:

```
private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

// ...

public StringProperty nameProperty() {
    return name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name.get();
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name.set(name);
}
```

Which allows you to do this in your controller:

```
partName.setCellValueFactory(f -> f.getValue().nameProperty());
```

Finally:  Remove the try/catch from your `start` method.  It’s not needed.